# Apollo iOS swift Always get from Local cache GraphQl

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, cache-control

When I use Apollo to deal with GraphQl API for every fetch in the first time only Apollo fetches from server else always fetch get from Local cache

```
let apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: graphQLEndpoint)!)
let meetingsQuery = AllMeetingsQuery()
apollo.fetch(query: meetingsQuery) { [weak self] result, error in
  guard let meetings = result?.data?.allMeetings else { return }
  print(conferences.count)
  self?.conferences = conferences.map {$0.fragments.meetingDetails }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every query from the server can be controlled by **CachePolicy**

A **Cache policy** that specifies whether results should be fetched from the server or loaded from the local cache.

```
public enum CachePolicy {
  /// Return data from the cache if available, else fetch results from the server.
  case returnCacheDataElseFetch
  ///  Always fetch results from the server.
  case fetchIgnoringCacheData
  /// Return data from the cache if available, else return nil.
  case returnCacheDataDontFetch
}
```

The default value is **returnCacheDataElseFetch** which mean  Apollo return data from the cache if available, else fetch results from the server.

I solved the problem by changing the cachePolicy with **fetchIgnoringCacheData**

```
apollo.fetch(query: meetingsQuery ,cachePolicy: .fetchIgnoringCacheData)  { [weak self] result, error in
  guard let meetings = result?.data?.allMeetings else { return }
  print(conferences.count)
}
```